# Interface for accessing JPA data with and without REST

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I would like to design an interface for accessing JPA data directly from within the Spring Boot application and also over REST.

Here is the interface for REST

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends    PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

This interface works correctly for REST access from an HTTP client.

I would also like to pre-populate the database by calling `repository.save()` from the Application class and then use `findByLastName()` to retrieve the list of names.

What is the way for this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what do you mean by pre populate the database using ```findByLastName```?

Comment: I have improved the comment description

Comment: I also don't get the question: simply call the repository method?